# Create dynamically named objects in a for loop in R and assign dynamic values

Tags: r

I am trying to create a suite of dynamically named new objects (e.g., `temp2015`) using a for loop, and storing dynamic values - specifically, the names of other objects (e.g., `Y2015`) and the value used in the for loop (e.g., `2015`) - in the dynamically named new objects.

I am not sure why the code below is not working.

```
Y2015 = data.frame(VAR1 = 6:10, VAR2 = 1:5)
Y2016 = data.frame(VAR1 = 7:11, VAR2 = 11:15)
Y2017 = data.frame(VAR1 = 7:11, VAR3 = 5:9, VAR4 = 4:8)

for (i in 2015:2017) {
  paste0("temp", i) <- cbind(names(paste0("Y", i)), i)
}

all <- rbind(temp2015, temp2016, temp2017)
```

The code below gets the result I want (specifically, the data content in the object `all_manual`) but this was done manually, on a very small sample dataset, and isn't a long-term solution.

```
Y2015 = data.frame(VAR1 = 6:10, VAR2 = 1:5)
Y2016 = data.frame(VAR1 = 7:11, VAR2 = 11:15)
Y2017 = data.frame(VAR1 = 7:11, VAR3 = 5:9, VAR4 = 4:8)

all_manual = data.frame(file = c('VAR1', 'VAR2', 'VAR1', 'VAR2', 'VAR1', 'VAR3', 'VAR4'),
                 year = c(2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017))
```

I'd greatly appreciate any advice or ideas about how to get this working.

Comment: What you are requesting is the use of `assign` and `get`, and you will find a significant amount of opposition to using those functions: they almost always indicate poor design. Since the frames all look the same I suggest you look into using a [list of frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358272): since you're likely to do the same or similar things to each frame, the use of `lapply` can greatly simplify the maintainability/flexibility of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mget` and `stack`

```
# creates a list of all objects with names starting with "Y" followed by 4 digits
l <- mget(x = ls(pattern = "^Y\\d{4}$"))
```

Now use `stack` to create a dataframe from the names of that list and the columns names of the dataframes that the list contains

```
out <- stack(sapply(l, names))
```

Result

```
out 
#  values   ind
#1   VAR1 Y2015
#2   VAR2 Y2015
#3   VAR1 Y2016
#4   VAR2 Y2016
#5   VAR1 Y2017
#6   VAR3 Y2017
#7   VAR4 Y2017
```

If you wish to remove the "Y" and make the `ind` to numeric, try

```
out$ind <- as.numeric(sub("Y", "", out$ind))
```

Change column names

```
names(out) <- c("file", "year")
out
#   file year
#1 VAR1 2015
#2 VAR2 2015
#3 VAR1 2016
#4 VAR2 2016
#5 VAR1 2017
#6 VAR3 2017
#7 VAR4 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution of markus recommended. But in case you wish to use a for loop.

```
for(i in 2015:2017){
  df <- get(paste("Y",i, sep = ""))
  df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(colnames(df), i))
  if(i == lower_year){result <- df1} else{result <- rbind(result,df1)}
  }
```